# Checkbox without checked attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been dynamically adding checkboxes to each row within a table - datatables.net .  However, when I check the boxes, the html does not show any checked attribute which then does not allow me to only focus on the rows with checked checkboxes.  If I set the checkbox with the checked attribute, then yes, the checked attribute is visible.  The code here shows how I'm trying to check the checked attribute...

```
        var filtered_rows = example_data_table._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});

        $.each(filtered_rows, function(i, el){
            // If not checked, do not include
            if(!$(el[0]).is(':checked')){
                console.log(el[0]);
                return true;
            }else{
                window.alert("HIT");
            }
         ...
```

and the following is how I'm appending the element to the datatables.net table...

```
        var checkbox = $("<input type='checkbox' 
                           id='checkbox_" + o.example_id + "' />");

        ...

        tmp = [checkbox[0].outerHTML,
        ...];
        table_data.push(tmp);

        ...

        example_data_table.fnClearTable(false);
        example_data_table.fnAddData(table_data);
```

In the console, all I get is this message n times:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_3895">                  examples.php:189
```

I guess, I'm wondering why the checked attribute is never included even when I have checked the checkbox?

Comment: The checked attribute shouldn't be shown, you're just not looking in the right place, it's the checked **property** that is changed, and that's not visible in the markup.

Comment: @adeneo is right, if you add it like this <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_3895" checked="checked">  you will see that the attribute checked will not change when you do check/uncheck. Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/pm9rat56/

Comment: Thanks, that definitely makes sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML markup attribute `<input checked=""` is not actually designed to show the state of the element at runtime moment, but to define the *default state of it when the page renders for the first time*.

[**MDN < input > docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) states:

> **checked:**
> When the value of the type attribute is radio or checkbox, the presence of this Boolean attribute indicates that the control is selected by default; otherwise it is ignored.

The only varying of checked state you can target is the Js DOM property `checked`:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').checked; //(true / false)
```

or the Css pseudo `:checked`:

```
#myInput:checked {
}
```