# Selenium Xpath for Salesforce Page checkbox - “checked” attribute is not present

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Issue: I am seeing difficulty to handle checkbox of Salesforce page. I am not seeing any difference 
between two state of Checkbox. Both state checked and non-checked are showing same classes, attributes and text. I am not sure how to handle the checkbox on Salesforce. 
Please see below screenshot. We do have Ids but they are dynamic so I can not use IDs in my test case.

Platform: JAVA, TestNG, Eclipse, Selenium

```
Only difference I see is when checkbox is selected then I can see below:
<span lightning-input_input="" class="slds-checkbox_faux" xpath="1">
: : after ==$0
</span>

when it's not checked the I can see below:

<span lightning-input_input="" class="slds-checkbox_faux" xpath="1">
</span>
```

What I tried so far which is not helping me on Salesforce page:

```
    String rr = driver.findElement(xpath).getAttribute("checked"); // not working

    isSelected(); // Not Working 

    document.getElementById('myInput').checked // Can not use this becasue of Dynamic ID
```

Below links I have gone through and tried locally on Salesforce page:

[Selenium checkbox attribute "checked"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187772/selenium-checkbox-attribute-checked)

[Xpath to determine checkbox "checked" attribute in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758616/xpath-to-determine-checkbox-checked-attribute-in-selenium-ide)

[Checkbox without checked attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107839/checkbox-without-checked-attribute)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @E.Wiest , you meant "//span[@class='slds-checkbox_faux'][contains(.,'after')]" ? just checked not working this xpath.

Comment: I meant `contains(//span[@class="slds-checkbox_faux"],"after")` (previous one was a mistake) ? XPath expession will return a boolean. Returns true = checked, returns false = unchecked.

Comment: check for element with  `span.slds-checkbox_faux::after` css after selecting. If the elements count return `0` then check box is not selected. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @supputuri thanks for your reply. No did not help me. I think the only solution left is to fire SOQL query to see the value ID is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike ASP I had similar scenario on a salesforce platform. Try using the xpath as
 **//*[@name='Existing_Tenant__c']** It worked for me. If you see multiple elements use index to get the element you intend to check. For ex **(//*[@name='Existing_Tenant__c'])[1]**. Just make sure that the xpath is highlighting the type='checkbox' tag in the DOM.

The following image is my scenario

[image]

Comment: my question was not just to locate element on Salesforce. Rather differentiate checked or non-checked element and create a unique Xpath for them. DOM is not showing difference between these two state for the element I highlighted in the question.

Comment: Not sure why you want an unique xpath. In my case I used **driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@name='Private__c'])[1])").isSelected()** that returns me true (if selected) or false (if not selected)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution.

Using below code with the help of Element Id

If Checkbox is checked:

```
String st=(String)js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],'::after').getPropertyValue('content')", element Id);
```

Output String Value will be  ""

If Checkbox is unchecked:

```
String st=(String)js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],'::after').getPropertyValue('content')", element Id);
```

Output String Value will be  none